# How to remove href attributes from a tag and remove css associated to it in iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a following set of codes in iframe with an id of #nitseditpreview:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nitsmenu" data-nitspagelabel="1">
        <li class="scroll active"><a href="#navigation">Home</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#ourteam">Our Team</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to remove href values from anchor tag and also css associated with it which is mentioned in a stylesheet i.e.:

CSS:

```
#navigation .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav  .active  a,  
#navigation .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav  .active  a:focus, 
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #fc7700;
}
```

I'm using jquery to execute this function, so far I am able to get the element by this:

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#nitseditpreview').load(function () { //The function below executes once the iframe has finished loading
    var menu = $(this).contents().find('#nitsmenu');
    $(this).contents().find('#nitsmenu' > li);
 }
}
```

Shall I use each function to get the desired output?

Comment: Do you want to remove href from anchor tag ?
If you remove the href then you can use this code : 

 $("#nitsmenu li a").removeAttr("href");

but the style is still working, If you want to remove style then you have to change anchor to span or any other tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This:

```
var all_li;
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#nitseditpreview').load(function () { //The function below executes once the iframe has finished loading
    var menu = $(this).contents().find('#nitsmenu');
    all_li = $(this).contents().find('#nitsmenu' > li);

    jQuery(all_li).find("a").removeAttr("href");
    jQuery(all_li).find("a").css({'color':'#000','background-color':'none' });
 }
}
```

I Added these two lines

```
 jQuery(all_li).find("a").removeAttr("href");
 jQuery(all_li).find("a").css({'color':'#000','background-color':'none' });
```

which remove all href and change css..